# How do I Select when the key of an association is a multi-word string

Tags: dataset, associations, query

I have imported some survey responses into a `Dataset`. I now want to select those rows where the response to "participant type" == "Virtual". I discovered that this works:

```
dataSet[Select[#[[2]] == "Virtual" &]]
```

But I want to know if there is anyway to say `#participant type`, instead of `#[[2]]`.

Comment: Use `#"participant type"`

Comment: Or `#[["participant type"]]` will also work.

Comment: Thank you both. I discovered that my previous attempts to implement Carl Woll's solution failed because I cut and paste the text into the formula. It looks like there is a bug in the parsing when one does that. However, typing the text gets round the problem.